# How to find whether there is single image or grid of images present in single frame using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here is the image:

[image: check this image]

How to find that there are total 9 images present in this frame?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img =  cv2.imread('viber_image_2020-05-13_16-47-36.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh_inv = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[2]
```

## Blur the image

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh_inv,(1,1),0)

thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[2]
```

## Find contours

```
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
for c in contours:
    # get the bounding rect
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if w*h>1000:
        cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), -1)

res_final = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask))

cv2.imshow("boxes", mask)
cv2.imshow("final image", res_final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cv2.Laplacian(gray_image) and np.mean() this (axis=0, axis= 1) for find grid edges.

Comment: i am new to open cv. can u please explain with example or give the code of same

Comment: after doing this step it will give some value. how to use that value?